Rasperry PI Python with Adafruit Rotary transducer
I am running python3 on a raspberry pi 3:
   Static hostname: raspberrypi
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 0bd95523f1a44b54abc9402a9f8f6b23
           Boot ID: 89ff548a7bb541daa4f9be88d6544fc6
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
            Kernel: Linux 5.10.103-v7+
      Architecture: ar

I am attempting to use the Adafruit rotary transducer (with I2C). The simple test program that I am using is the following:
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2021 John Furcean
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

"""I2C rotary encoder simple test example."""

import board
from adafruit_seesaw import seesaw, rotaryio, digitalio

# For use with the STEMMA connector on QT Py RP2040
# import busio
# i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL1, board.SDA1)
# seesaw = seesaw.Seesaw(i2c, 0x36)

i2c = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
# i2c = board.STEMMA_I2C()  # For using the built-in STEMMA QT connector on a microcontroller
seesaw = seesaw.Seesaw(i2c, addr=0x36)

seesaw_product = (seesaw.get_version() >> 16) & 0xFFFF
print("Found product {}".format(seesaw_product))
if seesaw_product != 4991:
    print("Wrong firmware loaded?  Expected 4991")

# Configure seesaw pin used to read knob button presses
# The internal pull up is enabled to prevent floating input
seesaw.pin_mode(24, seesaw.INPUT_PULLUP)
button = digitalio.DigitalIO(seesaw, 24)

button_held = False

encoder = rotaryio.IncrementalEncoder(seesaw)
last_position = None

while True:
    # negate the position to make clockwise rotation positive
    position = -encoder.position

    if position != last_position:
        last_position = position
        print("Position: {}".format(position))

    if not button.value and not button_held:
        button_held = True
        print("Button pressed")

    if button.value and button_held:
        button_held = False
        print("Button released")

When I run it I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seesaw_rotary_simpletest.py", line 7, in <module>
    from adafruit_seesaw import seesaw, rotaryio, digitalio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_seesaw/seesaw.py", line 43, in <module>
    from adafruit_bus_device.i2c_device import I2CDevice
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 15, in <module>
    from circuitpython_typing import ReadableBuffer, WriteableBuffer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/circuitpython_typing/__init__.py", line 79
    def read(self, count: Optional[int] = None, /) -> Optional[bytes]:
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It looks like something isn't loading correctly or I have the wrong version of something.

The error is from using / as a marker for positional-only arguments, which is new syntax added in Python 3.8. Debian buster, on which your version OS is based, has only Python 3.7. You need to use a newer OS, or otherwise get a newer version of Python (using pyenv or the like). This seems to be from a dependency and not the script itself, so you could try using older versions of dependencies.

I'd like to stress that is really just happening because you're using a version of your raspberry Pi OS that is two major releases behind the current Raspberry Pi OS: this is an excellent time to really update to a newer version. Your time postponing that is really running out, as you can see from exactly the things you are observing here! And, you're also running the 32 bit Raspbian on a 64 bit Raspberry Pi, which means you cannot make use of the power-saving SIMD instructions, so there's another reason to actually go and use a current Raspberry Pi OS (64bit)

Thanks for your help!!
